# Update Statement with hibernate switching unique key fields

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm not sure exactly where the error is coming from, unfortunately, but I have a guess and would like to know the best way to solve it.

**Problem**

Suppose we have the following table in the database

| ID | Field A | Field B | Field C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | C | Something |
| 2 | B | C | Something else |

And we have two unique indexes on the table

Unique-Index1 (ID)
Unique-Index2 (FieldA, FieldB)

Now I am loading both entities

```
        Session session = ...();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        TestTable dataset1 = (TestTable) session.get(TestTable.class, 1);
        TestTable dataset2 = (TestTable) session.get(TestTable.class, 2);
```

And now I want to do something like this

```
update testtable set fielda = 'B' where id = 1;
update testtable set fielda = 'A' where id = 2;
```

So at the end the unique key is not violated, but after the first statement, the unique index is violated.

In my JAVA application it looks like this

```
dataset1.setFieldA("B");
dataset2.setFieldA("A");

session.saveOrUpdate(dataset1);
session.saveOrUpdate(dataset2);

tx.commit();
```

After executing the application I get the following exception

```
Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Unfortunately, the error is not really meaningful. Also, I don't get any information whether it might be a duplicate or not. But if I delete the unique index, it works. So my guess is that it is because of that.

**Used frameworks / systems**

Java 17 SE application, using Hibernate 3.2 (very old version) with the legacy mapping XML files (so still without annotations). The database is an IBM Informix database.

The database model, as well as the indexes are not generated by Java, but by regular SQL scripts.

I can't change anything about the versions of Hibernate or the database either, unfortunately. Also I cannot influence how the index was created. This all happens outside the application.

**Idea**
The only idea I had was to first change all records that need to be changed to fictitious values and then set the correct values again. But that would mean that two update statements are triggered per record, right?

Something like this:

```
dataset1.setFieldA("XXX");
dataset2.setFieldA("YYY");

session.saveOrUpdate(dataset1);
session.saveOrUpdate(dataset2);


dataset1.setFieldA("B");
dataset2.setFieldA("A");

session.saveOrUpdate(dataset1);
session.saveOrUpdate(dataset2);

tx.commit();
```

However, I am not even sure if I need to commit the transaction. Maybe a flush or something similar is enough, but the solution is not really nice. I can kind of understand the problem, but I would also have thought that this would be legitimate within a transaction then - only at the end of the transaction the constraints have to be correct.

Many greetings and thanks for your help,

Hauke

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either you configure the unique constraint to be "deferrable" and also mark it as "initially deferred" so that the constraint is only enforced at transaction commit time, or you delete and re-insert the entries.

I would suggest you to use the first option if your database supports this. You didn't specify which database you are using, but [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-altertable.html) supports it. You'd only have to run `alter table test_table alter constraint your_unique_constraint deferrable initially deferred`.